# Converting SWF file to animated GIF (preferreably, command line)

Tags: actionscript-3, bash, flash, gif, animated-gif

I have an SWF file that contains a simple animation (spinning ball), which I want to convert into an animated GIF.

Ideally, I would like to use a command line (bash script) to do this. Can anyone suggest any links to get me started (Google is not coming up with anything useful).

In the event that there is no bash command for the SWF to GIF conversion, I may have to use ActionScript. In this case, any pointers to get me started would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about command line, but Adobe Flash Professional allows to export (publish) your projects as GIF.

Comment: @Jari: Unfortunately, I don't have Adobe Flash Pro. Do you knoe if I can use the trial edition to export the file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint, how to use as3.0, First your spinning ball animation capture using a Bitmapdata's [draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29). and using a [GIFEncoder](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=93), create a GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jari said, Flash Pro can do this out of the box.
Not sure about a Bash script, but there are a ton of free tools you can use
for example

[Mac SWF2GIF](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/SWF2GIF.shtml)

and Yes, the Trial version of Flash Pro will be able to do it aswell! But i recommend a slim Tool like in the link

My bad, couldnt find anything for Linux on the fly, but just search for "Linux swf 2 gif converter"
Or u can upload it and i'll quickly convert it ^^

Comment: Will this application work on a Linux (Ubuntu) box?. It seems to be for MAC OS?

Comment: i thought u where on a mac cous of the Bash script. I updated the Answer with a Linux link (first i found, there will be loads)